# how to sum/aggregate by group without using pandas or import

Tags: python

so I am basically not allowed to use any import or other libraries like pandas or groupby.
and I have to categorize the data and sum up the corresponding values. The data is in the csv file.
For example,

```
**S** C  **T**
A      T           100
A.     B           102
A.     T.          200
A      B.          100
C    T           203
C.   T.          200
C    B           200
C  T          200
C. B          200
```

my expected result should be

```
S      C   T

A      T       300
A     B.      202
C    T       403
C    B.      200
C  T.      200
C   B.     200
```

Comment: Loop over the data and collect in a dictionary `{(state, candidate): votes}`

Comment: Does your file actually have such punctuation and typos? Does it matter for you?

Comment: sorry I was in a hurry to post it and it is my typo and punctuation

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you have a csv file (i.e., columns split by comma):

```py
with open('myfile.csv', 'r') as file:
    header = file.readline().rstrip()
    data = {}
    for row in file:
        state, candidate, value = row.split(',')
        k, value = (state, candidate), int(value)
        data[k] = data.get(k, 0) + value

result_csv = '\n'.join([header] + [f"{','.join(k)},{v}" for k,v in data.items()])
print(result_csv)
```

Output:

```
state,candidate,total votes
Alaska,Trump,300
Alaska,Biden,202
colorado,Trump,403
colorado,Biden,200
California,Trump,200
California,Biden,200
```

---

Original content of `myfile.csv` is (use `str.replace` if necessary):

```
state,candidate,total votes
Alaska,Trump,100
Alaska,Biden,102
Alaska,Trump,200
Alaska,Biden,100
colorado,Trump,203
colorado,Trump,200
colorado,Biden,200
California,Trump,200
California,Biden,200
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    mylist = []
    
    with open("data", "r") as msg:
        for line in msg:
            mylist.append(line.strip().replace(".",""))
        msg.close()
    
    headers = mylist[0].replace("*","").split()
    
    del mylist[0]
    
    headers[2] = headers[2]+" "+headers[3]
    
    mydict = {}
    
    for line in mylist:
        state = line.split()[0]
        mydict[state] = {}
    
    for line in mylist:
        state = line.split()[0]
        candidate = line.split()[1]
        mydict[state][candidate] = 0
    
    for line in mylist:
        state = line.split()[0]
        candidate = line.split()[1]
        votes = line.split()[2]
        mydict[state][candidate] = mydict[state][candidate] + int(votes)
    
    print ("%-15s %-15s %-15s \n\n"  % (headers[0],headers[1],headers[2]))

    for state in mydict.keys():
        for candidate in mydict[state].keys():
            print ("%-15s %-15s %-15s"  % (state,candidate,str(mydict[state][candidate])))
```

Output:

```
state           candidate       total votes     


Alaska          Trump           300            
Alaska          Biden           202            
colorado        Trump           403            
colorado        Biden           200            
California      Trump           200            
California      Biden           200
```